# range joins in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, left-join

Given two dataframes, I need to filter the records in `df2` based on the the ranges for similar ids in `df1`.  I was wondering if there is a better (faster) way than the naive approach shown below.  In my use case, `df1` has 100million records and `df2` has over a billion records.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([["A",10,20],["B",5,8]],
  columns=["id","start_dt_int","end_dt_int"]))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([["A",15],["A",25],["B",9]],
  columns=["id","enc_dt_int"]))

comb = [df1.id==df2.id, df1.start_dt_int<=df2.enc_dt_int, df2.enc_dt_int<=df1.end_dt_int]
df2.join(df1, on=comb, how="leftsemi").show()
```

Comment: I think you can also achieve this with LEFT join and SELECT like 'df2.*' as well. But, LEFTSEMI is much efficient then LEFT only join. That could be big factor for you since you are working with alot of data

Answer (score 0):

Lets try range join using spark sql

create database tables

```
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')

df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')
```

Range join and then drop unwanted columns

```
spark.sql("""SELECT *
FROM df2
  JOIN df1 ON (df2.id = df1.id)
  and df2.enc_dt_int BETWEEN df1.start_dt_int AND df1.end_dt_int""").select([df1.id, 'enc_dt_int']).show()
```

Output

```
+---+----------+
| id|enc_dt_int|
+---+----------+
|  A|        15|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  On my data this isn't running faster than the above.